# Python problems installing ROS on OS X 10.9

Tags: ros, python, mavericks, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by the helpful folk at the question "Building ROS on OSX 10.9 (solution)", ID 94771 (this forum won't let me post questions with links), I'm opening a new question to deal with the Python issues I'm facing.

Originally, I went through the ROS Hydro brew-based installation instructions. There were a number of issues with individual packages that were addressed in the answer to the question referenced above, but there's also an issue with using Brew's Python, the recommended solution to which is to use the system Python. I'm now trying to do that, but it's not clear to me how to restore the packages needed by Brew and ROS to make that work. The last issue was with upgrading sip (although it's not clear to me if this should be done through Brew or separately, as to keep with the system Python):

https://gist.github.com/wjwwood/3f93c45c2edabd07a44a

I never use Python, and apologize for having very little clue about its environment. Appreciate the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151276/python-problems-installing-ros-on-os-x-10.9/) by [JetForMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/8636/jetforme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I were in your shoes, I would:

- delete my build, devel, and install folder (of my catkin workspace)
- uninstall python from brew
- uninstall any brew formulae which used python (sip pyqt pyside pyqwt etc..)
- remove the contents of the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
- and start over.

It is definitely over kill, but in my experience it is very difficult to repair the damage of mixing the system and brew pythons.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2